# How to append to an existing file using FireDAC

Tags: delphi, firedac

I would like to write to an existing .csv file not create a new one every time it runs. Here is the code I have so far.

```
with TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader.Create(FDBatchMove) do begin
      DataSet:= Inventory.mInventoryCount;
      Optimise:= False;
    end;
    with TFDBatchMoveTextWriter.Create(FDBatchMove) do
    AssignFile(myFile, 'C:\Dataout.csv');
    //FileName:= ExtractFilePath('C:\') + 'DataOut.csv';
    Append(myfile);
    FDBatchMove.Execute
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to do writing by yourself. That's what the writer does for you. You need to just control the [**Mode**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Mode) property and the clear options of the [**Options**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Options) option set of the [**TFDBatchMove**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove) to instruct the engine what the writer should do. From what you say it sounds like you are interested in the **dmAlwaysInsert** mode (which is default) and keeping **poClearDest** and **poClearDestNoUndo** options not included in the option set (which is default as well).

Or in other words, FireDAC will append data with no checks to the destination by default, hence the problem you've described could have happen by modifying some of the mentioned settings (or, you just misidentified the issue).

Comment: Yes that is the mode it is set on but it seems to remove any cell formatting I have on the cells in that document.

Comment: You cannot have cell formatting in CSV. CSV is just a pure text file. Or what exactly happens? Could we see a short example of the file before export and after?

Comment: Well that explains it why I format the cells and then When i run the program there is not format. Thank you